# Why $X_{f^*s} = f^{-1}(Y_s)$ ( $f^{*}s$ is the pull-back of a section $s$ under $f : X \to Y$) )?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am reading the Gortz's Algebraic Geometry, proof of Proposition 13.65 and stuck at understanding some statement.

**First**, I arrange some several related notions.

- *Definition 1.* Let $(X,\mathcal{O}_X)$ be a locally ringed space and let $\mathcal{L}$ be an invertible $\mathcal{O}_X$-module. Let $s \in \Gamma(X,\mathcal{L})$ be a global section. By definition there exists for every point $x\in X$ an open set $U$ of $x$ and an isomorphism $w: \mathcal{L}|_U \to \mathcal{O}_X|_U$. We say that *$s$ is invertible in $x$*, if $w_x(s_x) \in \mathcal{O}_X^{\times}$. We can also express this as $s(x) \neq 0 \in \mathcal{L}(x)$, where $\mathcal{L}(x):=\mathcal{L}_x/\mathbb{m}_x \mathcal{L}_x = \mathcal{L}_x \otimes_{\mathcal{O}_{X,x}} \kappa(x)$ and $s(x)$ is the image of the germ $s_x \in \mathcal{L}_x$ in $\mathcal{L}(x)$.

Then we define

$$X_s:= X_s(\mathcal{L}) := \{ x\in X : s \operatorname{is invertible in }x\}$$

C.f. In Liu's Algebraic Geometry book notation ( his book p.166 ),

$$ X_s := \{ x\in X : \mathcal{L}_x = s_x \mathcal{O}_{X,x}\}.$$

( But I don't certainly sure that these two definitions are coincide )

- *Definition 2.* ( pull back of sections under $f$ ) Let $f : X \to Y$ be a morphism of ringed space and $\mathcal{G}$ be a $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module. Using the canonical homomorphism $\mathcal{G} \to f_*(f^* \mathcal{G})$ we define for every open subset $V\subseteq Y$ a map

$$ f^* = f_V^* : \Gamma(V,\mathcal{G}) \to \Gamma(V,f_*(f^*\mathcal{G})) = \Gamma(f^{-1}(V), f^{*}\mathcal{G})$$

which we call the pull back of sections under $f$.

**Second**, I propose a question. Let $f:X\to Y$ be a scheme morphism ( of finite type ) and $G:=\mathcal{K}$ be a invertible $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module.
Let $s\in \Gamma(Y, \mathcal{K})$ and $f^*s \in \Gamma(X, f^{*}\mathcal{K})$ be its pull back.

**Q.** **Then my question is, $X_{f^*s} = f^{-1}(Y_s)$ ?**

My first attempt is as follows :

First, refer to next question : [What is a simple definition of the pullback of a section?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3490373/what-is-a-simple-definition-of-the-pullback-of-a-section). Let  $G:= \mathcal{K}$. In the answer of Alex Kruckman in the linked question, the image of $s\in G(Y)$ under long chain of maps $$G(Y)\to f^{-1}_\text{p}G(X) \to f^{-1}G(X) \to f^{-1}G(X)\otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y(X)} \mathcal{O}_X(X)\to f^*G(X)$$ is the pull back $f^*s\in f^*G(X)$. (True?)
Following this maps, my first guess of explicit form of $f^*s$ is, by letting $1_X \in \mathcal{O}_X(X)$ be the identity,

$$ s \mapsto [s] \mapsto ([s]_x)_{x\in X} := ( [(X,[s])]_{f_P^{-1}G,x})_{x\in X} \mapsto ([s]_x)_{x\in X} \otimes 1_X  \mapsto f^{*}s \overset{\mathrm{?}}{=} (([s]_x)_{x\in X} \otimes 1_X)_{x\in X} $$

(C.f. Gortz's book proof of Proposition 2.24 ; there the morphism $\iota_{\mathcal{F}} : \mathcal{F} \to \tilde{\mathcal{F}}$ from a presheaf to its sheafification is defined.) True? Is there a point that I made ( notational ) mistake?
And if this is ture, then can we show $X_{f^*s} = f^{-1}(Y_s)$? How? Things seem to be getting more complicated :) A priori, calculations required to prove it seem complex.

Can it be proved only by brutal force?

Or is there any other simpler route to show this statement? Can anyone helps?

In fact, this question originates from follwing proof of the Proposition 13.65 in the Gortz's Algebraic Geometry book :

> Proposition 13.65. Let $S$ be a quasi-compact scheme, let $f:X\to Y$ and $g:Y\to S$ be morphisms of finite type. Let $\mathcal{L}$ be an $f$-ample $\mathcal{O}_X$-module and let $\mathcal{K}$ be a $g$-ample $\mathcal{O}_Y$-module. Then there exists an integer $n_0$ such that $\mathcal{L}\otimes f^{*}(\mathcal{K})^{\otimes n}$ is ample for $g \circ f$ for all $n \ge n_0$.

*Proof.* As we can cover $S$ be finitely many affine schemes, we may assume that $S$ is affine. The existence of $\mathcal{L}$ and of $\mathcal{K}$ implies that $X$ is separated over $Y$ and that $Y$ is separated over $S$. Therefore $X$ and $Y$ are quasi-compact separated schemes.
We find an integer $d>0$ and finitely many sections $t_i' \in \Gamma(Y, \mathcal{K}^{\otimes d})$ such that the $Y_{t_i'}$ form an open covering of $Y$ ( Proposition 13.47 ). ( We aceept these statements. If needed, I will upload more detailed explanation. )  Let $t_i \in \Gamma(X, f^{*}\mathcal{K}^{\otimes d})$ be the pull back of $t_i'$ (7.8.11). **Then $X_i:=X_{t_i} =f^{-1}(Y_{t_i'})$ and the $X_i$ covers $X$.** As $\mathcal{L}|_{X_i}$ is ample ( omitted.. )

Why $X_{t_i} =f^{-1}(Y_{t_i'})$ is true? Can anyone helps?